# Can a Bot receive image as message or attachment from a user

Tags: c#, botframework

I want a user to be able to send image as message to Bot. is this possible?. I've searched online for solutions and I'm tired. please can someone share me a link at least?.

Comment: Pleas show some attempt

Comment: "I've searched online for solutions and I'm tired": Serioulsy? we too.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

From the `nodejs` documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-send-receive-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

```
// Create your bot with a function to receive messages from the user

var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector, function (session) {
    var msg = session.message;
    if (msg.attachments && msg.attachments.length > 0) {
     // Echo back attachment
     var attachment = msg.attachments[0];
        session.send({
            text: "You sent:",
            attachments: [
                {
                    contentType: attachment.contentType,
                    contentUrl: attachment.contentUrl,
                    name: attachment.name
                }
            ]
        });
    } else {
        // Echo back users text
        session.send("You said: %s", session.message.text);
    }
});
```

`c#` documentation is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-add-media-attachments?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

Comment: I mean i wan to send attachment to bot as a message, not to receive attachment from bot. I've studied the documentation but not what i am looking  for. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes you can providing the channel you are using allows for attachments. Channels have limits on things like size and file types so this will vary depending on what channel you are using.  So if you cannot get a PDF to work try with an image. If an image doesn't work, try with a smaller image.

Users will upload a file via the channel interface like this in the emulator:
[image: emulator file upload]

There is no special code needed to receive images in your bot.  Images will be present in the `Activity` as `Activity.Attachments` This is a `List` of the attachments, or in your case images.  This could have easily been inferred from Rajesh's answer, but for completeness here is an example of doing something with a file received:

In `RootDialog.cs`

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs;
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Bot_Application15.Dialogs
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RootDialog : IDialog<object>
    {
        public Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            foreach (var file in activity.Attachments)
            {
                //where the file is hosted
                var remoteFileUrl = file.ContentUrl;
                //where we are saving the file
                var localFileName = @"C:\Users\{UserName}\pictures\test" + file.Name;

                using ( var webClient = new WebClient())
                {
                    webClient.DownloadFile(remoteFileUrl, localFileName);
                }
            }
            await context.PostAsync($"File received");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes , it is possible in your MessageRecivedAsync Method of Bot Dialogue .

```
    private async Task MessageReceived(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
    {
        var message = await result;
        if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
        {
            // Do something with the attachment
        }
        else
        {
            await context.PostAsync("Please upload a picture");
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
    }
```