# How to get attachment uploaded by bot user

Tags: c#, botframework

```
public virtual async Task MotgaAtt(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
        {
            var message = await argument;
            if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
            {
                var attachment = message.Attachments.First();
                using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {
                    var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);
                    var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;
                    await context.PostAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
                }
            }

            context.Done<object>(new object());
        }
```

I want to get the uploaded attachment by the bot user so i can insert it in the database. I tried to use the attachment variable i created but it seems not to be the exact file the user uploaded. Please how do i get the uploaded file?. Thanks

Comment: "I tried to use the attachment variable i created but it seems not to be the exact file the user uploaded" < what is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a Bot receive image as message or attachment from a user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50488713/can-a-bot-receive-image-as-message-or-attachment-from-a-user)

Answer (score 1):

See official samples: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/CSharp/core-ReceiveAttachment

Depending on the channel you must give a specific token:

```
public virtual async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument)
{
    var message = await argument;

    if (message.Attachments != null && message.Attachments.Any())
    {
        var attachment = message.Attachments.First();
        using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            // Skype & MS Teams attachment URLs are secured by a JwtToken, so we need to pass the token from our bot.
            if ((message.ChannelId.Equals("skype", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) || message.ChannelId.Equals("msteams", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
                && new Uri(attachment.ContentUrl).Host.EndsWith("skype.com"))
            {
                var token = await new MicrosoftAppCredentials().GetTokenAsync();
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
            }

            var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(attachment.ContentUrl);

            var contentLenghtBytes = responseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentLength;

            await context.PostAsync($"Attachment of {attachment.ContentType} type and size of {contentLenghtBytes} bytes received.");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Hi there! I'm a bot created to show you how I can receive message attachments, but no attachment was sent to me. Please, try again sending a new message including an attachment.");
    }

    context.Wait(this.MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, But can you please guide me on how to get a hold of the attachment so i can the create a database connection and save it in database ?. I need create a variable for the received attachment.